# How can I solve this ASP error '80040e14'?

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm creating a webpage where users can delete information from the database and I'm getting an error message from the database that says this.

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'
>
> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ID='.
>
> /courses/benv/2410/2013s2/3420384/assign3/delete.asp, line 50

I believe it is because there is a value that was supposed to be passed by the form but is missing. However, I can not see where I am missing.

Here is the webpage code. Line 50 is in stage 2.

```vb
<% option explicit %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <!--#include file="dbconn.asp"-->
  <!--#include file="header.asp"-->
  <%
  dim stage, s, sql, info
  stage = request.form("stage")
  if stage = "" then stage=1

  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  if stage = 1 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

    '--- get all the posts
    '            0      1               2         3
    SQL="SELECT ID, projectName, description, Created"&_
    " FROM ProjectsTable"&_
    " ORDER BY ID"
    set info=conn.execute(SQL)

    '--- create a radio-button list of the current posts
    response.write "<br>" &_
    "Please select the post to be deleted:" &_
    "<form action=""delete.asp"" method=""post"">" &_
    "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value=""2"">"
    do
    response.write "<input type=""radio"" name=""posttobedeleted" &_
    " value="""&info(0)&""">"&info(1) &_
    " "&info(2)&" "& info(3) & "<br>"
    info.movenext
    loop until info.eof
    response.write "<input type=""submit"" value=""Delete Post!"">" &_
    "</form>" 

  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 2 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

  %>
<!-- #include virtual="/courses/benv/2410/show_form_content.asp"-->

<%

  dim deletePost
  deletePost = Request.Form("posttobedeleted")
  sql = "delete * from ProjectsTable where ID="& deletePost
  conn.execute(sql)

  response.write  "The specified suburb has been deleted." 

  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  end if  ' stage
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

  response.write "<br clear=""left"">" &_
  "<br>"
  if stage=2 then
  response.write "<i>that's all folks!</i><br>"
  end if
  response.write "<a href=""./"">back to main page</a>"
  conn.close
  %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you selected any radiobuttons before hitting `Delete Post!`?

Comment: @cha yes. At the moment I only have one because I'm just testing.

Comment: @cha just tried adding another radio button. Same message.

Comment: Instead of calling conn.execute() for the delete statement, try to `response.write sql` and see what the sql string contains.

Comment: @cha It just says this: delete * from ProjectsTable where ID=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
response.write "<input type=""radio"" name=""posttobedeleted" &_
    " value="""&info(0)&""">"&info(1) &_
    " "&info(2)&" "& info(3) & "<br>"
```

Try to change it to:

```
response.write "<input type=""radio"" name=""posttobedeleted"" value=""" &_
info(0) & """>" &_
info(1) &_
" " & info(2) & " " & info(3) & "<br>"
```

Explanation: I think by separating "" you have broken the proper initialisation of radiobuttons. I recommend you install a FireBug or something in Firefox and "inspect element" for your radiobuttons

Comment: +1.  Specifically, the problem is with `&_ "` -- it's leaving off the closing `"` for the radio button name, thus not being able to `request ` its value.  Your solution should work, or the OP can just add 2 additional `"` after the line break.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I would vote you up but my reputation is not high enough. Many thanks for your help.